# Can pcie slots on two hosts transmit data through cables?

Tags: networking, pci-express, data-transfer

Both PC motherboards and server motherboards now support pcie interfaces, which are very fast.If the pcie between two PCS can be connected directly to transfer data, they can be faster than regular networks.If used to transfer terabytes of data, it can save more time and hardware costs.After all, 10GB plus network modules aren't cheap

Comment: You would have to have them on the same bus or have an intermitten modem. That modem is a 10 GB plus NIC as an example. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552684/direct-pcie-to-pcie-connection-for-communications) question for some more information.

Comment: PCIe signals don't particularly like cables, nor do they particularly like having "host" devices on both sides of the link. One way or another you need special cables and some kind of "interface" device pretending to be something like, for example, an ethernet controller. PCIe has a limit on length due to the signal properties so the computers would have to be literally side by side for it to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic in PCI-Express; I think earlier generations even use roughly the same signal format as Gigabit Ethernet does. At least part of the magic is in it being a *very short distance* connection.

> Can pcie slots on two hosts transmit data through cables?

PCIe over a cable – yes, that's what Thunderbolt is, basically. USB4 and Thunderbolt literally support [PCIe tunnelling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/testref/7d627bf0-25f3-4564-b554-b2a3450e2bcf) for connecting e.g. docks or external GPUs to your computer.

But it cannot be used between two hosts, as far as I know. (And it doesn't use the actual PCIe signalling; it carries PCIe data *over* Thunderbolt signalling.)

However, Thunderbolt/USB4 *also* supports "XDomain" mode which allows IP networking between two hosts directly connected using a Thunderbolt cable. This doesn't use the PCIe tunnelling feature, it's slightly more direct.

> Both PC motherboards and server motherboards now support pcie interfaces, which are very fast.If the pcie between two PCS can be connected directly to transfer data, they can be faster than regular networks.If used to transfer terabytes of data, it can save more time and hardware costs.After all, 10GB plus network modules aren't cheap

I believe part of why they aren't cheap is because they need to deal with considerably longer distances and lower-quality cables (compare to the ~10 cm between your CPU and the PCIe slots) – if you tried to stretch a PCI-Express connection across the room, you'd soon need the same expensive shielded cables and complex signalling that 10Gb+ Ethernet needs.

Comment: PCIe signalling is, as you hint, somewhat stringent and requires length and impedance matched cables. USB3 cables are "close enough" for short lengths and only single link hence GPU miners use them, but I'd hate to see how expensive an x16 link cable would get and PCIe has a maximum length due to wire losses which can quickly mount up. Tunnelling it over a more cable oriented signal protocol such as Thunderbolt is the best we can manage.

Comment: The price tag comes not so much from fact of shielding and cable materials - though that adds too - but more from the fact that these cables house an onboard chip that is squashing multiple IO streams into single copper wire - kind of similarly how you can tune the frequency band of your radio to listen to a particular station - the cable is using different frequency bands to transmit different IO streams. Essentially the cable is not just a dump cable but is also doing encoding and decoding.